# Pro Rata - Calculate the amount of shares to buy

Tags: investing, shares, start-up

A company gets incorporated with only 2 stakeholders:

- 1st stakeholder has 250 shares (a.k.a 33.33%)
- 2nd stakeholder has 500 shares (a.k.a 66.67%)

Price per share: 1$

On it's first financing round:

- Price per share remains the same
- 1st stakeholder wants to buy 250 shares
- How many shares should 2nd stakeholder buy to stay even on ownership?

In this case it's obviously 500 shares.

My question is, how do i calculate those 500 shares using a formula?

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading this right, but I think the 2nd stakeholder cannot "buy more" because there are only 2 stakeholders that own all of the shares. so the 1st would have to buy 250 shares from the 2nd, essentially flipping their ownership. If new shares are being introduced by the company, then the calculation is 500 * ((250 + 250) / 250) = 1000 to keep the 2:1 ratio. In otherwords it is P2 * (F1 / P1) = F2, with F1 = P1 + A1. where P is Principal and A is Additional and F is final.

Comment: Yes, new shares are being introduced by the company.
The question is 1st stakeholder wants to buy 250 shares, but 2nd stakeholder wants to stay even. So how many more share will have to be printed to keep the distribution.

About the formula you posted, it seems to only hold comparing against 1 stakeholder, but what if there are more?